# <nav> won't abide to body

Tags: html, css, width

I'm really not sure that my title is correct english. Hehe. But fortunately I can explain my problem in pictures ;-)

My problem is this:

[image]

```css
body {
  font: calibri;
  background-color: #2d2e29;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0.75;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 30%;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
}
nav a {
  margin: 5px;
  color: black;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #99cccc;
}
#Forside {
  background-color: #3f5c93;
  height: 800px;
}
#Mig {
  background-color: #ccc2a6;
  height: 800px;
}
#Faerdigheder {
  background-color: #3f5c93;
  height: 800px;
}
#Projekter {
  background-color: #ccc2a6;
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#Kontakt {
  background-color: #3f5c93;
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#logo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background: url("Logo.png");
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <nav>
    <!-- navigations-element (menu) -->
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <!-- internt link: relativ URL -->
        <a class="nav" href="#Forside">
          Forside 
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <!-- internt link: relativ URL -->
        <a class="nav" href="#Mig">
          Mig 
         </a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <!-- internt link: relativ URL -->
        <a class="nav" href="#Faerdigheder">
          Færdigheder
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <!-- internt link: relativ URL -->
        <a class="nav" href="#Projekter">
          Projekter 
         </a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <!-- internt link: relativ URL -->
        <a class="nav" href="#Kontakt">
          Kontakt
         </a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="Forside">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>Forside
  </div>
  <div id="Mig">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="meleft">
      <h1>Mig</h1>
      <p class="textleft">Lots of words
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="meright">
      <img src="sdp.png" alt="sdp" id="sdp1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Faerdigheder">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="skillsleft">
      <img src="Collage1.png" alt="Collage" id="Collage" />
    </div>
    <div class="skillsright">
      <h1>Færdigheder</h1>
      <p class="textright">Lots of words
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added my code to fiddle, so you can see the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Lj6ck3L/

I hope you can understand the code even though some words is in Danish :-)

Comment: your header is position fixed, so its taken out of the flow of its parent, so your the parent elements width wont have any effect on it. try position relative on the parent of the header and position absolute on the header

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the HTML and CSS provided, set the width of the `nav` to `calc(100% - 300px);`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/9Lj6ck3L/12/)

Otherwise you are telling it to be the full viewport width, offset from the left by 150px which is why it seems to overspill to the right. Using `calc` you can say, "fine, stretch to the viewport width, but minus the margins"

Comment: Hey SW4. Thank you so much. I was not aware of the "calc(100% - 300px);"-thing. I think it will be my new favorite ^^ It work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/9Lj6ck3L/11/

Changed width of your header bar.

```
nav {
                    position:fixed;
                    width:63.5%;
                    height:80px;
                    background-color:#FFFFFF;
                    opacity:0.75;
                    top:0;
                    left:0;
                    margin-left:150px;
                    margin-right:150px;
                }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `position:fixed`. This element does not inherit anything from it's parent in terms of width.

Your best bet would be to wrap the nav in another `<div>` and make that position fixed. Then give the `<nav>` inside it the width that you want.

Move the `<nav>` outside of the `#all` div and put your margins on `#all` instead of the body.

Then give your `<nav>` css of `box-sizing: content-box` or `box-sizing: padding-box` to solve the width issue.